# Having trouble in a volleyball simulation- stuck in a loop

Tags: python

Good afternoon, I'm trying to simulate a volleyball game based in the probability that each team has to win a point. Basically I am stuck in a loop even tho I have conditions that should make it stop. The problem is in my Set25P function. The code follows:

*mostly code fillllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllll*

```
import random

def main():
    Intro()
    probA, probB = Data()
    winsA, winsB = Sets4(probA, probB)
    winsA, winsB = Set5(probA, probB, winsA, winsB)
    

def Intro():
    print("This program simulates a volleyball match")
    print("between two teams: Team A and Team B.")
    print("The result of the match varies according")
    print("the probability of each team.")

def Data():
    probA = eval(input("Whats the probability that Team A wins the point? "))
    probB = eval(input("Whats the probability that Team B wins the point? "))
    return probA, probB

def Set5(probA, probB, winsA, winsB):
    if winsA == winsB == 2:
        scoreA, scoreB = Set15P(probA, probB)
        if scoreA == scoreB + 2 and scoreA >= 15:
            winsA += 1
        elif scoreB == scoreA + 2 and scoreB >= 15:
            winsB += 1
    return winsA, winsB

def Set15P(winsA, winsB, probA, probB):
    serving = "A"
    scoreA = 0
    scoreB = 0
    while True:
        if not (scoreA == scoreB + 2 and scoreA >= 15) or not (scoreB == scoreA + 2 and scoreB >= 15):
            if serving == "A":
                if random.random() < probA:
                    scoreA += 1
                else:
                    serving = "B" 
                    scoreB += 1
            else:
                if random.random() < probB:
                    scoreB += 1
                else:
                    serving = "A" 
                    scoreA += 1
        elif scoreA == scoreB + 2 and scoreA >= 15:
             winsA += 1
             break
        
        elif scoreB == scoreA + 2 and scoreB >= 15:
             winsB += 1
             break
        
    return winsA, winsB

def Sets4(probA, probB):
    winsA = 0
    winsB = 0
    for i in range(4):
        winsA, winsB = Set25P(winsA, winsB, probA, probB)
        if gameOver(winsA, winsB):
            break
    
    return winsA, winsB

def Set25P(winsA, winsB, probA, probB):
    serving = "A"
    scoreA = 0
    scoreB = 0
    while True:
        if not (scoreA == scoreB + 2 and scoreA >= 25) or not (scoreB == scoreA + 2 and scoreB >= 25):
            if serving == "A":
                if random.random() < probA:
                    scoreA += 1
                else:
                    serving = "B" 
                    scoreB += 1
            else:
                if random.random() < probB:
                    scoreB += 1
                else:
                    serving = "A" 
                    scoreA += 1
        elif scoreA == scoreB + 2 and scoreA >= 25:
             winsA += 1
             break
        
        elif scoreB == scoreA + 2 and scoreB >= 25:
             winsB += 1
             break
        
    return winsA, winsB
    

def gameOver(winsA, winsB):
    if winsA == 3:
        print("Team A wins the match")
        return True
    elif winsB == 3:
        print("Team B wins the match")
        return True
    else:
        return False    

if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```

Comment: Try printing `scoreA` or `scoreB` somewhere in your method, and see if the numbers make sense.

Comment: @JhanzaibHumayun I have done that before the while loop in the Set25P and the numbers just keep going, like the set never ends. The numbers do make sense since the team with the bigger probability has more points.

Comment: print them inside the loop and see if they ever fullfill the condition `scoreB == scoreA + 2 and scoreB >= 25`. And if not, why?

Comment: Now, I am confused, you said that you printed the values before the while loop in Set25P, but in that case they should only print once and the while loop should never end. I am assuming that the problem lies with the while loop, because that's what you wrote in your question, but if your print statement managed to print more than once, then the problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: In order for `not (scoreA == scoreB + 2 and scoreA >= 25)` to be `False` both conditions (`scoreA == scoreB + 2` and `scoreA >= 25`) would need to be `True`. What are the chances that your randomizer is going to create a `scoreA` score greater than 25 AND `scoreB` is going to be exaclty 2 fewer. There is only the tiniest tiniest chance that BOTH `not` conditions return `False` allowing you to break the loop. It's tiny tiny tiny though.

Comment: I think taking a step back and thinking through what you are trying to do with this condition (and knowing scoring of volleyball) something like ` if (scoreA < 25 and scoreB < 25) or (abs(scoreA - scoreB) < 2):` is a little easier to parse and doesn't cause an infinite loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding on my comments. Your conditions in your `if` and `elif` are wrong for what you are trying to achieve and you've wrapped yourself in big inescapable boolean straight jacket.

You want the loop to continue if neither score is greater than 25 or (if it is greater than 25) the difference in the scores is less than 2. So write that logic as-is without the `not`:

```
def Set25P(winsA, winsB, probA, probB):
    serving = "A"
    scoreA = 0
    scoreB = 0
    while True:
        if (scoreA < 25 and scoreB < 25) or (abs(scoreA - scoreB) < 2):        
            if serving == "A":
                if random.random() < probA:
                    scoreA += 1
                else:
                    serving = "B" 
                    scoreB += 1
            else:
                if random.random() < probB:
                    scoreB += 1
                else:
                    serving = "A" 
                    scoreA += 1
        elif scoreA > scoreB:
             winsA += 1
             break
        
        elif scoreB > scoreA:
             winsB += 1
             break
```

Note I also changed your `elif` conditions since there is no reason to do extra checking at this point. It's merely "Who won?".

As for troubleshooting, next time sprinkle some `print()` statements inside your loop and see what the values are of your scores. It will help illuminate the issue.

Comment: It makes much more sense like this lol I'm still trying to improve the efficiency of my code and this helped a lot in trying to view things from a different POV. Thank you very much, its now working perfectly!

Comment: Monkeying with complicated conditions like this can get confusing fast. If you want to further shorten the code, I believe Python supports the following syntax: `if scoreA < 25 > scoreB or abs(scoreA - scoreB) < 2:`. I'm not a python expert though so you may want to double check that (although it works in my tests).

Answer (score 0):

Tried running the code, and found that the problem lies with the line

```
if(scoreA == scoreB + 2 and scoreA >= 25)
```

You probably want `scoreA >= scoreB + 2 and scoreA >= 25`. The problem currently is that scoreA can only win if it's scoreB+2 AND larger than 25. Meaning that a score of 27-23 doesn't mean that scoreA wins because scoreB + 2 = 25, which is not scoreA.

Comment: I see, i failed at considering that cenario. Thank you very much!!